# Connect to remote SQL Server 2008 on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, connection-string

I created a local MSSQL database with my ASP.NET project.

Now I want to connect to my database hosted in www.abc.com

What should I put in the connectionString ?

Comment: Is this also where the website is hosted?  As in, the web server and the database server are the same PC?

Comment: Do you mean your database is on the local host?

Comment: Here:http://www.connectionstrings.com/ you can find what you need

Comment: I developed the app locally and now I want to use a remote MSSQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with your hosting provider (abc.com). Some hosting providers don't allow remote connection to their databases, and require you to use their web application to access your database.

If they do allow access, they should provide you with SQL Authentication details of:

- Server Name
- Database Name
- Username
- Password

An example of a SQL connection string would be:

```
Data Source={server name/ip};Initial Catalog={database name};User ID={username};password={password}; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

Comment: I have access to the remote database, and I already created the database and associated a user to that database. I need just the full connectionString

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of a connection string that I use

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Server Explorer` tool of Visual studio to get the connection string. (Right click on Data Connections + Add Connection).

Answer (score 0):

```
 "Data Source=Your_Server_Name;Initial Catalog= Your_Database_Name;UserId=Your_Username;Password=Your_Password;"
```

or

```
 "Data Source=Your_Server_Name;Initial Catalog= Your_Database_Name;integrated security=true"
```